# (React Navigation 5): Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I use version 5 React Navigation.

And according to the [React Navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#replace)  I use the `replace` as below

```js
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
  })
);
```

But I get following error

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Upgrade your dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `StackActions` import source

```js
import { StackActions } from "@react-navigation/routers/src/StackRouter";
```